# ошибка LINK2001 Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-c++

Подключил библиотеку pjsua для реализации простого софтфона. Регистрация проходит нормально. Однако при создании объекта на вызов вылетает ошибка. Библиотеки подключил все, которые есть необходимы для работы. Классы определяет нормально все видит. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как "подключали" библиотеку? В каком она виде у вас?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Сначала собрал проект из исходников и получил .lib, далее добавил на поиск include в проекте на папку со всеми h файлами библиотек. И часть библиотек работает нормально, а у этой при переопределении методов вылетают ошибки с непонятным описанием.

Comment: А lib-файл вы специально подключали к проекту? Собирали его Студией, кстати?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я lib подключал в h файле через `#pragma`. Все классы определяются. Класс который отвечает на регистрацию на сервере, подключается и возвращает ответ. А другой, который отвечает за вызов при переопределении методов вылетает с этой ошибкой. Хотя  в исходных файлах .cpp перед сборкой были эти методы.